# Entity Framework Core DbContext OnConfiguring does not exist anymore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

It was a while ago i used Entity Framework Core so I don't know if they have simply deleted the virtual OnConfiguraing method in the DbContext class or assembly or what you call it. But I have search everywhere and their are no answer.
I have tried changing from V17 and V19 but its the same on both.

**What I am trying to do**:
Using Entity Framwork, i am trying the Code First Approach.
The code below used to work.

(Taken from docs.microsoft)
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Integrated Security=True");
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

**What I get**
[disappearance of onconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08LIp.png)

As you can see on the image, the OnConfiguring should be after Model property but its not there anymore.

**Question**: Does anybody know why OnConfiguring has disappeared from DbContext?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the image you provide you are trying to override with the "public" modifier. The override for OnConfiguring is "protected".

Try writing "protected override" and intellisense should pick it up for you.

Comment: You are correct.. however the intellisense does not show up on protected. Only on public and OnConfig does not exist there.